# How to integrate properly Tiles 3 with Struts2 ?

Tags: java, struts2, tiles-3, struts2-tiles-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Tiles 3 with Struts 2.

I guess I've added all the necessary jar files in the lib but I get:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
                    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<listener>
<listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>    
<display-name>My Application</display-name>
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>    
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
```

**tile.xml**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
<definition name="baseLayout" template="/baseLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="MyProject"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="menu" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="footer" value=""></put-attribute>
</definition>
<definition name="homePageLayout" template="/homePageLayout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="MyProject-HomePage"></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="header" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="leftMenu" value=""></put-attribute>
    <put-attribute name="body" value=""></put-attribute>    
    <put-attribute name="rightMenu" value=""></put-attribute>   
</definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

**struts.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false"></constant>
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResource"></constant>
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default"> 
 <result-types>
    <result-type name="tiles" class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
</result-types>     
  <default-action-ref name="index"/>

    <action name="ShowLogin"><result>login.jsp</result></action>
    <action name="Login" class="com.myproject.action.Login">
        <result name="success">login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: RTM: http://struts.apache.org/docs/tiles-3-plugin.html or http://struts.apache.org/docs/tiles-2-plugin.html.

Comment: It would be good to use the updated DTD also : http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To integrate Tiles 3 with Struts 2 you need to use the [struts2-**tiles3**-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/tiles-3-plugin.html), not the [struts2-**tiles**-plugin](https://struts.apache.org/docs/tiles-2-plugin.html).

You are using the **Tiles2 Listener**:

```xml
<listener-class>
    org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
</listener-class>
```

The right one is the **Tiles3 Listener**:

```xml
<listener-class>
    org.apache.tiles.extras.complete.CompleteAutoloadTilesListener
</listener-class>
```

You are also using the wrong **Struts2 Filter**:

```xml
<filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
```

Use the complete one:

```xml
<filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
</filter-class>
```

Comment: thanks dear @Andrea ...
I remove struts2-tiles-plugin jar file but I still get the same error :(

Comment: Thanks I change my JAR files version and using your advic ...it worked

Answer (score 0):

Look like you miss the `struts2-tiles-plugin.jar` in your classpath. Add it and the error should gone.

Comment: dear @Jens I add all the necessary Jar file in /WEB-INF/lib

Comment: @samansv error clearly says that you are missing the class which is in `struts2-tiles-plugin`. You are adding jars or using maven?

Comment: I know I add struts-tiles-plugin and struts-tiles3-plugin in the /lib

Comment: @samansv the class in in struts2-tiles-plugin.jar. as i can see it is not in the plugin you use.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are missing the jar/dependency which has `org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener` class, which is `struts2-tiles-plugin` jar. Just check out [search.maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Aorg.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener)

If you want to download the jar, download it from the same link.

If you are using maven, add this dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5-BETA1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks dear @Reservoir but I add the struts-tiles-plugin and struts-tiles3-plugin JAR file but I still get the same error :(